# Pork vs chicken ramen

Tags: broth, ramen

I frequent a place that makes thick tonkotsu (pork based) ramen, so that is my point of reference. But I recently tried a new place that only makes chicken based broths and, for the same size bowl, I found it to be *extremely* filling to the point of being uncomfortably full

How is chicken broth typically made? and is there some ingredient in there that causes it to be much more filling than pork based broths?

The 2 places in question:

- http://ramendanbo.com/our-menu-vancouver/
- https://marutama.ca/menus/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't know since we don't have the exact recipes, but I have a few good guesses.

Pork broth is made by boiling pork bones, so the thickness comes from the extracted collagen. Chicken broth is usually made by boiling chicken carcasses, which is mostly meat and bones. That will make a lighter broth since there's not a lot of fat.

I came across a recipe for [creamy chicken paitan broth](https://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2018/12/chicken-paitan-broth.html) which is made with the whole chicken then blended and strained, so you end up with lots of protein in the broth which will make it heavy.

Another one uses [chicken wings](https://www.thekitchn.com/how-to-make-a-rich-and-flavorful-chicken-broth-for-homemade-ramen-236301) and that will extract a lot of fat, which will also make you feel full quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Thick chicken soup are made the same way as tonkotsu but with different cooking time because thickness of the bones. Some soup make you fuller because its more viscous and or contain more fat. viscous because of gelatine and emulsified fat